# Eliminar elemento de un array con REST operator

Tags: javascript

resulta que estoy haciendo los ejercicios de The Odin Project y aunque ya los he completado todos, este último lo he completado googleando mucho, viendo varios videos de YT y memorizándolo, y lo último que me interesa es memorizarlo, más bien quiero emplear la lógica.

El ejercicio te pide que crees una función, que el primer parámetro (array) sea una sucesión de números y que el segundo parámetro elimine los números del array, tal que así:

removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2, 3) luego quedaría en removeFromArray([1, 4, 5]).

El código es este:

```js
const removeFromArray = function(...args) {
    const array = args[0];
    const newArray = [];
    array.forEach((item) => {
        if (!args.includes(item)) {
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    })
    return newArray;
}

console.log(removeFromArray([2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4, 6));
```

Me gustaría entender bien la lógica... sé lo que hacen las funciones, he leído sobre los REST parameters (que es lo que se usa en el código), sé sobre el método forEach() y sé lo que hace push pero no termino de entender la lógica... por qué el args tiene un [0]? no funcionaría igual sin él? Y si el if del forEach que se ejecuta en cada iteración tiene un !NOT !args.includes(item)? donde incluye el newArray.push(item) el item exactamente? Estoy muy perdido y de verdad que quiero entender la lógica de este ejercicio.... Podría alguien ayudarme, "descomponer" el código y explicármelo?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El código que pones hace una cosa. Dado un array de entrada y una lista de elementos, devuelve un array con todos los elementos del array que no se pasaron por parámetros.

#### ¿Cómo lo logra?

1. Crea un arreglo de salida.  (`const newArray = [];`)
2. Para cada elemento del array de entrada  `array.forEach((item) => {`:

   - ¿El elemento actual NO está incluido en la lista de parámetros prohibidos?  `if (!args.includes(item)`

     - Correcto: el elemento actual no se incluye en la lista de parámetros prohibidos. Agrega el elemento al array de salida `newArray.push(item);`
     - Incorrecto, es un elemento prohibido: Continúa con el siguiente elemento sin agregar este elemento a la salida.
3. Devuelve el array de salida.

#### ¿Cómo obtengo el arreglo de entrada?

Rest Parameters significa que todo lo que le pases a la función va a pasar dentro cómo un array. Por ejemplo, si llamas a la función con:

```
 removeFromArray([1,2,3], 4,6)
```

Lo que va a llegarte adentro es:

```
args = [[1,2,3], 4,6]
```

Otros ejemplos son:

```
removeFromArray([1,4,4,3], 4, 6, 7) // Hace que args = [[1,4,4,3], 4, 6, 7]
removeFromArray([1,3], 4, 6)        // Hace que args = [[1,3], 4, 6]
```

Como ves, todo lo que le pasas adentro a la función te llega "empacado" en un arreglo. Esa es la magia de los Rest Parameters.

---

Sabiendo esto ¿Cómo obtienes el arreglo que es pasado a la función? ¿por qué args tiene un [0]?

Nota que el arreglo que se le pasa a la función SIEMPRE ESTÁ en la primera posición del arreglo de Rest Parameters, por tanto, para obtenerlo debes indexar args en 0:

```
// Si args = [[1,4,4,3], 4, 6, 7] entonces args[0] = [1,4,4,3]
const array = args[0];
```

---

### Método `include` de los arreglos

El método `include` en un arreglo devuelve `true` si el arreglo incluye el elemento pasado por parámetro y `false` si no lo incluye. Por ejemplo, si tengo el arreglo:

```
arg = [[1,3], 4, 6]
```

Y quiero ver si incluye el número 1 (`arg.includes(1)`), el método include revisará elemento por elemento a ver si el uno está incluido.

- Primer Elemento: ¿Es `[1,3]` igual a `1`? NO
- Segundo Elemento: ¿Es `4` igual a `1`? NO
- Tercer Elemento: ¿Es `6` igual a `1`? NO

Como no encontré ningún elemento que sea igual a 1, devuelvo `false`, porque `[[1,3], 4, 6]` NO INCLUYE un `1`.

---

Sabiendo lo que hace `args.includes`, puedes saber lo que hace `!args.includes`.

- `args.includes` devuelve verdadero si args incluye al elemento
- `!args.includes` devuelve verdadero si args NO incluye al elemento

---

### Código con comentarios:

```js
const removeFromArray = function(...args) {
    const array = args[0];   // Obtiene el array de entrada y lo guarda en la variable array
    const newArray = [];     // Crea un nuevo array
    array.forEach((item) => { // Para cada elemento del array de entrada
        if (!args.includes(item)) { // Si el elemento del array de entrada no está incluido en la lista de parametros prohibidos
            newArray.push(item); // Agrega el elemento al array de salida
        }
    })
    return newArray; 
}

console.log(removeFromArray([2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4, 6));
```

Simplificado:

```js
const removeFromArray = (...args) => args[0].filter((item) => !args.includes(item))
console.log(removeFromArray([2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4, 6));
```

Separando la lista de elementos prohibidos y el array de entrada:

```js
const removeFromArray = (array, ...args) => array.filter((item) => !args.includes(item))
console.log(removeFromArray([2, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4, 6));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación, de verdad, me ha ayudado mucho, no sabes el tiempo que llevaba rompiéndome la cabeza con este ejercicio.

Gracias de nuevo!!!